# jquery validation(length & numbers) for phone number

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4

I have created field as required. I tried some ways to validate input and length it's not working.

**my functions is:**

```
function Validate(code){
            if(jQuery('#'+'shipping_form_'+code).length != 0){
                jQuery('#'+'shipping_form_'+code).show();
                jQuery(this).find('.required-entry').attr('disabled','false');
               /* if(jQuery(this).find('.required-entry').length < 11){
                    alert('Account Number should be 6 digits')
                */}
            }
        }
```

How to validate length & input(numbers only)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built in Magento form validation and use either the **validate-phoneStrict** or **validate-phoneLax** class.

```
<form name="phone-form" id="phone-form" method="post">
    <label for="firstname">
        <?php echo $this->__('Phone number') ?> <span>*</span>
    </label>
    <input  id="firstname" name="firstname" class="input-text  required-entry"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var phoneForm = new VarienForm('phone-form');
//]]>
</script>
```

If you then need to manually call the validation function in some other javascript you can simply do

```
var validator = new Validation($('phone-form'));
if(validate.validate()) {
    alert('validated');
}
```

See more here:
http://blog.magestore.com/2010/04/09/magento-form-validation/